# Docker container shutdown script

Tags: php, bash, nginx, docker

Is there any way to have a bash script get executed when a container is shut down?

Use case:

- there is a **master** container running **nginx + php-fpm**
- there is a **foo** (project) container that uses volumes and links to the **master**
- ubuntu 14.04 is used as the base for all images

When **foo** is started it plops in a vhost config file for nginx to use (as well as adds the project to the webroot, etc., etc.)

What we want to achieve is that when **foo** is stopped it will do a cleanup (delete the vhosts file, remove the project from the webroot, etc.)

Setting up **/etc/rcX/KX-cleanup** does not work.

The only other option to explore it seems - is to have some bash-sigterm-listener in the entryscript in an infinite loop (will this waste precious CPU cycles?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Docker and the PID 1 zombie reaping problem](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/)" and "[Trapping signals in Docker containers](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86)", docker send SIGCHLD or SIGTERM on `docker stop`/`docker kill`.

If your `foo` app can monitor those signals, or if the `foo` process can provide callbacks, it can trigger any script you want.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  console.log('shutting down...');
});
```

Note:

> When creating a Dockerfile, make sure you use exec form of `ENTRYPOINT` or `RUN` commands.
>   Otherwise the application will be started as a subcommand of `/bin/sh -c`, which does not pass signals.
>   The container’s PID1 will be the shell, your application will not receive any signals from the `docker kill` command.

Note: soon (Q4 2015), docker 1.9 will allow your container to specify the stop signal it wants to react to, with the new `STOPSIGNAL` dockerfile directive. See [PR 15307](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15307).